# Apex Inbound Service

Tags: apex

Is it possible to build something like an "inbound" service within force platform?

Kind of a custom logic controlled by an apex class which can we called via REST Api from external services with different parameters? And the apex class would manage inserts/updates across different objects. I'm aware you can use the normal REST Api for direct object access, bit i'm looking for an object flexible solution.

Hope it's clear what I mean.

Comment: Your edited question is much less clear. Are you not trying to create an inbound REST service?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You can define REST services using Apex. See the below linked article from the Technical library (emphasis mine):

> ## [Creating REST APIs using Apex REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST)
>
> #### Abstract
>
> The [Force.com REST API](http://developer.force.com/REST) lets you use a simple and lightweight API to access Force.com data, using standard OAuth, together with a choice of data flavors – XML and JSON. The REST API is configured out of the box to suit the basic CRUD (create, read, update and delete) operations of data management.
>
> **Apex REST augments this functionality and makes it possible for developers to create your own REST-based web services using Apex. It has all of the advantages of the REST architecture, provides the ability to define custom logic and includes automatic argument/object mapping.**
>
> This article provides an introduction and overview of the Apex REST functionality, showing you how to take your first steps in creating REST-based web services in Apex. As Apex REST builds on the Force.com REST implementation itself, the [Getting Started with the Force.com REST API](https://www.salesforce.com/resources/articles/inbound-marketing/) article is recommended reading.